# Input box not selectable over HTML5 canvas

Tags: css, html5-canvas

```
<div style="position:relative;width:800px;height:800px">
    <canvas width="800" height="800"></canvas>
    <input type="text" style="position:absolute;left:100px;top:300px; width:600px;z-index:9999" />
</div>
```

I have implemented a textbox over an html5 canvas object. However though I can see the input I am unable to select or enter anything into the box. Is there a reason why the input box is not selectable?

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue. Your html is not misbehaving for me using Chrome, FF, Edge, IE on Win10.

Comment: Canvas is by default transparent but is likely on top /try fill canvas with a solid color to check). The short example does not reproduce the problem (and z-index does not necessarily do what you think it does).